# SciPy: what is a "generalized" continuous random variable?

Tags: python, numpy, random, scipy

I was trying to implement a half-logistic distribution and came across [**halflogistic**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.halflogistic.html) and [**genhalflogistic**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.genhalflogistic.html).

- halflogistic: "A half-logistic continuous random variable."
- genhalflogistic: "A generalized half-logistic continuous random variable."

This "generalized" version comes up for some of SciPy's other continuous random variables as well, such as [**gennorm**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gennorm.html).

My question is: what does "generalized" mean and how is it different from the non-generalized version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Generalized" means having one or more additional parameters which somehow affect the shape of the distribution. To find what they are, compare the probability density functions. Let's start with normal:

```
norm.pdf(x) = exp(-x**2/2)/sqrt(2*pi)
```

versus

```
                             beta
gennorm.pdf(x, beta) =  ---------------  exp(-|x|**beta)
                        2 gamma(1/beta)
```

Here, beta is the additional parameter. If beta = 2, you get the normal distribution (scaled a bit differently compared to `norm`). With 0 < beta < 2 you get other [stable distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution).

It's a bit more confusing with half-logistic, though, because the formulas do not look alike:

```
halflogistic.pdf(x) = 2 * exp(-x) / (1+exp(-x))**2
```

versus

```
genhalflogistic.pdf(x, c) = 2 * (1-c*x)**(1/c-1) / (1+(1-c*x)**(1/c))**2
```

But [taking the limit as c→0](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%202%20*%20(1-c*x)**(1%2Fc-1)%20%2F%20(1%2B(1-c*x)**(1%2Fc))**2%20as%20c%20to%200) in the latter formula gives the former. So, c is the shape parameter here. The support of generalized half-logistic is the interval [0, 1/c]. The limit form c→0 has infinite support [0, ∞).

Comment: So with the generalized version you can create a half-logistic distribution with an upper limit, whereas with the non-generalized version your upper limit is always infinity?